# How get get image links that are displayed on google search right hand side

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

When you search for, say Bill Gates, on google,

[https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=1&tok=tZLQEkbVdJM-Nt6k14b-hA&cp=6&gs_id=3p&xhr=t&q=bill+gates&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=bill+g&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=c2c622f5707131aa&biw=1868&bih=732](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_nf=1&tok=tZLQEkbVdJM-Nt6k14b-hA&cp=6&gs_id=3p&xhr=t&q=bill+gates&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=bill+g&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=c2c622f5707131aa&biw=1868&bih=732)

you get these images on the side. I am wondering where they are coming from any api to pull out these image links ?

I tried custom search API of google. I dont seem to get these as it searches by the domains I specified (like google, wikipedia, etc).

Comment: I need to find out the image locations of the images on the right hand side. An API to find that list of images is what I am actually looking for

Comment: I doubt you are allowed to have these images anyway

Answer (score 3):

Google uses Freebase, semantic web representation of wikipedia, for it's knowledge graph. You can get api key from Google API console and made queries against freebase for finding such images.
More Information : http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/ApiImage

Other options are, you can use dbpedia ( which is also semantic web representation of wikipedia) to find such results.